# Oracle pl/sql script which increments number

Tags: oracle, plsql

Looking for a way to create an Oracle script using the equivalent of java ++ syntax to increment a variable.

Ie:

```
int id=10
DELETE MYTABLE;
INSERT INTO MYTABLE(ID, VALUE) VALUES (id++, 'a value');
INSERT INTO MYTABLE(ID, VALUE) VALUES (id++, 'another value');
...
```

Trying to use a variable and not a sequence so I can rerun this multiple times with the same results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PL/SQL doesn't have the `++` syntactic sugar.  You'd need to explicitly change the value of the variable.

```
DECLARE
  id integer := 10;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM myTable;
  INSERT INTO myTable( id, value ) VALUES( id, 'a value' );
  id := id + 1;
  INSERT INTO myTable( id, value ) VALUES( id, 'another value' );
  id := id + 1;
  ...
END;
```

At that point, and since you want to ensure consistency, you may be better off hard-coding the `id` values just like you are hard-coding the `value` values, i.e.

```
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM myTable;
  INSERT INTO myTable( id, value ) VALUES( 10, 'a value' );
  INSERT INTO myTable( id, value ) VALUES( 11, 'another value' );
  ...
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [SEQUENCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) to increment a number.

```
----CREATING SEQUENCE:                                                                                                                                                      

    SQL> create sequence seq_name
    2  start with 1
    3  increment by 1
    4  NOCACHE
    5  NOCYCLE
    6  ;
```

Sequence created.

```
----EXECUTION:                                                                                                                                            
SQL> select seq_name.nextval from dual;   

NEXTVAL                                                                                                                                         
1

SQL> select seq_name.nextval from dual;                                                                                                                 

NEXTVAL     
2
```

Also you can create a function that can be called anywhere:

```
----CREATING FUNCTION:     
create or replace function sequence_func(a_number IN Number)
RETURN Number
AS
id Number;                                                                                                                                         
Begin                                                                                                                                              
select seq_name.nextval into id from dual;    
Return id;
end;
/
```

Function created.

```
----EXECUTION:  
SQL> select  sequence_func(1) seq from dual;  
seq
1
```

P.S :
*startwith* and *increment by* values below can be set as per your requirement.